# How to control a global counter in behave?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

I am trying to use environment file functions in `behave` to maintain a counter variable. My implementation looks like this:

```
def before_all(context):
    context.counter = -1

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    print(context.counter)

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.counter += 1
```

I have a `.feature` file with multiple `scenario`. But always getting the same value for each `scenario`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Show the rest of the class. You are not accessing `context.counter` in `before_all`, but `context.g2tsjson_scenario_counter`.

Comment: @Memristor sorry, it was a typo. I indeed accessing the same counter. What I am trying to do is, for each scenario in a feature file, I am forming a small dict with an id key. So for the whole feature file, I have a list of dict. Now, as the counter always stays same, some of fields are getting value only in the first dict, rest of them doesn't contain any value.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is simple: you can't do that in Behave, the values modified during a execution are no persistent over successive Scenarios.

The explanation: that is a very dangerous idea because you are creating **dependent** scenarios. You always have to design **independent** scenarios so you can execute any of them in any order.

I'll give you an example: you have two consecutive Scenarios which are dependent:

```
Scenario 1:
 Given I get the counter with value -1
 When I sum 1 to the counter
 Then The counter's value is 0

Scenario 2:
 When I sum 1 to the counter again
 Then The counter's value is 1
```

You have a very dangerous dependency here, hence you must always execute the Scenario 1 before Scenario 2. You should change the implementation as the following:

```
Scenario 1:
 Given I get the counter with value -1
 When I sum 1 to the counter
 Then The counter's value is 0

Scenario 2:
 Given I get the counter with value -1
 And I sum 1 to the counter
 When I sum 1 to the counter again
 Then The counter's value is 1
```

As you see, I've repeated some steps from Scenario 1 in Scenario 2, but in that way I achieve the independence of both Scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to maintain a global counter across all scenarios (and features):

```py
SCENARIO_COUNTER = 0

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    global SCENARIO_COUNTER  # pylint: disable=global-statement
    SCENARIO_COUNTER += 1
    # ... a use-case specific to Playwright:
    video_path = context.page.video.path()
    video_path_new = f'{SCENARIO_COUNTER:05}__'
    video_path_new += scenario.status.name + '__'  # passed or failed
    video_path_new += scenario.filename.split('/')[-1] + '__'
    video_path_new += scenario.name.replace(' ', '_') + '.'
    video_path_new += video_path.split('.')[-1]  # extension
    os.rename(video_path, video_path_new)
```

Although usually indeed it is better to not share any global state across scenarios in order to keep each scenario repeatable and runnable independently of any other, this is still a valid use case that allowed me to prefix each output video file name by scenario sequence number and make it easy to understand exactly what happened in which order during `behave` without even looking at any logs.

EDIT: The behave [documentation](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/context_attributes.html) suggests that it should be possible to keep user-defined attributes for the duration of the whole `behave` test run, but this did not work for me as-of `behave==1.2.6`

> #### User Attributes
>
> A user can assign (or modify) own attributes to the context object.  But these attributes will be removed again from the context object depending where these attributes are defined.
>
> ```
> | Kind | Assign Location | Lifecycle Layer (Scope) |
> | Hook | before_all()    | test run                |
> | Hook | after_all()     | test run                |
> ...
> ```